# Getting current flavor using gradle.startParameter not working

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I tried getting value of current flavor set in Android Studio using gradle.startParameter.taskRequests in my app's build.gradle but every time I am getting [DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[],projectPath='null'}] as the value. In this args is [ ].

Please help me in getting current flavor set in Android Studio.

[image: build.gradle screenshot]

Comment: There is no "current flavor". Your Gradle script builds an object model of how to build software. Only when Android Studio actually goes to use that object model is there a "current flavor".

Comment: @CommonsWare  Then is it possible to include a dependence for all flavors except one using a loop and not by defining individual configurations.

Comment: I do not know if the Gradle DSL supports that, but in theory it should be possible.